# Postfix attempting to bind to port 25, used for outgoing mail only (maybe not necessary?)

Tags: email, docker, postfix-mta

Not sure if this belongs on Stack Overflow or somewhere else but I'll try here first.

I have multiple servers, each with the same setup where nearly everything running on the server is in a docker container. I have two goals I would like to achieve. First, the host machine is setup to send emails for users with uid < 1000 to my external email address. Second, on one server, I have a docker-mailserver container running to handle random, seldom used emails (for log files, etc.).

It seems I can have either the host machine running postfix OR the docker-mailserver running (and bound to port 25). Currently, I have the docker container, running the mail server, full operational and everything can send and receive just fine.

However, now I am unable to start postfix on the host machine so that I can receive emails sent to the root user (things like cron output) since port 25 is --rightfully-- in use by the actual mail server receiving email.

Questions:
1) How can I tell postfix on the host to not bind to port 25? If port 25 is only used for receiving mail, why would my outgoing-only postfix config need to use port 25?
2) I am perfectly comfortable not receiving emails for the root user, if whatever would normally be sent to the root user is logged elsewhere (perhaps, syslog?). Are the emails to root only maintained as emails or are they somewhere else, negating the need for postfix on the host for forwarding to a real account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically answering your questions first:

1. You should be able to have postfix listen on any port you specify by editing the `main.cf` configuration file and changing the `smtp` listener to a numbered port of your choice. Of course, if it isn't a "known" port, I'm not sure what/who will ever connect to it, but maybe you don't care in this situation as you are only using postfix as a relay?
2. It may depend some on the Linux distribution or setup of your host, but most systems will leave email in the local delivery "mail spool" if there is no system/daemon set up to move it anywhere else. Back when that was the normal way to handle multi-user mail on UNIX systems, a login user used a mail reader client to read through email in your local "spool", and of course if you don't have that, you can simply `vi` your mail file and read the raw contents if necessary. These mail files are normally located in `/var/spool/mail` on most systems.

Stepping away from your questions, I would guess you don't necessarily need `postfix` running on your host, especially as your containerized mailserver is handling the port 25 SMTP traffic for the host. Local email will stay local, I assume, without postfix, and be available through local means; and you might even find a simpler solution to external forwarding (e.g. a script that can parse mail spools and just connect to an SMTP relay and send it to an external address) if you want that.

Comment: Thanks Phil. After a little testing I decided to not install any mail server on the host and instead find other ways to get data off the server. For instance, unattended-upgrades logs are now forwarded (along with other syslogs) to a central logging server for review and alerting.